# SimpleForm position for boolean variable is odd

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1 Update, SimpleForm 3.0.1

I'm just trying to build a basic form for a new associate, and I cannot get the Boolean variable :shared to line up.  I've tried to reposition it, make it a checkbox, whatever.  I know it's probably something basic...

It's the last box on the lower left in the picture:

[image]

PostgreSQL lists the variable as shared, Boolean, FALSE.

The form is:

```
<div class="span8">
  <%= simple_form_for Associate.new,
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input(:name, {autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'New associate name?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:logon, {autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Logon?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:cell, {autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Cell?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:secret, {autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Secret?'}) %>
      <%= f.input(:manager, {autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Manager\'s Logon?'}) %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, Role.where(name: "admin"), :id, :name) do |b|
        b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.check_box + " Administrator?" } end %>
      <%= f.input(:shared, as: :boolean)  %>
      <%= f.button(:submit, class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The schema is:

```
  create_table "associates", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "logon",                        null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "cell"
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "crypted_password",             null: false
    t.string   "salt",                         null: false
    t.boolean  "shared",                       null: false
    t.integer  "manager_id"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.string   "remember_me_token"
    t.datetime "remember_me_token_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add "boolean_style: :inline" into the statement.

```
  <%= f.input(:shared, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline) %>
```

EDIT:
The above change corrected the alignment problem as asked.  However, it then became impossible to correctly label the checkbox.  I finally found the fix at 
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/424

There are several options and permutations there, as well as discussions.  Also, the fix as presented had some errors.  The changes that I made that worked follow.

Final HTML statement:

```
= f.input(:shared, label: "Shared device?", boolean_style: :inline, input_html: {checked: false}, wrapper: :checkbox )
```

Added to config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb:

```
  config.wrappers :checkbox, tag: 'div', class: 'control-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input
    end
  end
```

Added to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

```
//Checkbox right fix
label.checkbox {
  text-align: left !important;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```